# SpriteKit delete node using removeFromParent does not work

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, removechild

In my game I need to delete some nodes completely and try to do it, using button `Delete!`. My test node disappears but still have size, color and position (see prints in my code). I found some previous
discussions on the similar topic, but it doesn't help. How is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, ButtonDelegate {

  // Basic for dynamic sizes step 01
  var width = CGFloat()
  var height = CGFloat()

  var btnDelete = Button() // new button class
  var testNode = SKSpriteNode()

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

     // Basic for dynamic sizes step 02
     width = self.frame.size.width
     height = self.frame.size.height

     setBtnDelete()
     setTestNode()
     self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

  }

  func deleteNode(){
     testNode.removeFromParent()
     testNode.color = UIColor.cyan
     print("# func deleteNode() testNode.position after delete :\(testNode.position)")
     print("# func deleteNode() testNode.color after delete :\(testNode.color)")
     print("# func deleteNode() testNode.size after delete :\(testNode.size)")
  }

  func setTestNode(){
     testNode.size = CGSize(width: width*0.3, height: width*0.3)
     testNode.position = CGPoint(x: width*0.5, y: height*0.5)
     testNode.color = UIColor.red
     self.addChild(testNode)
  }

  func buttonClicked(sender: Button) {
    //print("# you clicked the button named \(sender.name!)")
    deleteNode()
  }

  func setBtnDelete(){

    btnDelete = Button(texture: nil, color: .orange, size: CGSize(width: width*0.2, height: width*0.1))
    btnDelete.name = "btnDelete"
    btnDelete.position = CGPoint(x: width*0.5, y: height*0.18)

    btnDelete.delegate = self
    btnDelete.zPosition = 2
    addChild(btnDelete)

    btnDelete.label.text = "Delete!"
    print("# func setBtnDelete() btnDelete.name:\(btnDelete.name!)")

  }
}
```

class button code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

protocol ButtonDelegate: class {
   func buttonClicked(sender: Button)
}

class Button: SKSpriteNode {

   //weak so that you don't create a strong circular reference with the parent
   weak var delegate: ButtonDelegate!
   var label = SKLabelNode()

   override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {
      super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
      setup()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      setup()
   }

   func setup() {
      isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      setLabel()
   }

   func setLabel() {
      label.zPosition = 1
      label.text = "Test"
      label.fontName = "Chalkduster"
      label.fontSize = 34
      label.numberOfLines = 0
      label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
      label.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
      label.fontColor = UIColor.darkGray
      label.fontName = "Chalkduster"

      self.addChild(label)

   }

   func btnDie() {
      self.isHidden = true
      self.removeFromParent()
   }

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      setScale(0.9)
      self.delegate.buttonClicked(sender: self)
   }

   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      setScale(1.0)
   }
}
```

Comment: You have a strong reference to `testNode` (line 11). If you make the variable an optional `SKSpriteNode` and set it to `nil`, the memory will be released.

Comment: Many thanks 0x141E, that was the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update (see comment above):

testNode should be optional:

```
 var testNode:SKSpriteNode?
```

Then (by delete function) it can be set to nil and the memory will be released.